# Either getting original return value from xargs or simulate xargs

Tags: bash, xargs, exit-code, variable-expansion

I am working with bash. I have a file F containing the command-line arguments for a Java program, and I need to store **both** outputs of the Java programs, i.e., output on standard output and the exit value. Storing the standard output works via

```
cat F | xargs java program > Output
```

But xargs does not give access to the exit-code of the Java program.
So well, I split it, running the program twice, once for standard output, once for the exit code --- but getting the exit code and running it correctly seems impossible. One might try

```
java program $(cat F)
```

but that doesn't work if F contains for example " ", namely one command-line argument for program which is a space. The problem is the expansion of the argument $(cat F).

Now I don't see a way to get around that problem? I don't want "$(cat F)", since I want that $(cat F) expands into many strings --- but I don't want further expansion of these strings.

If on the other hand there would be a better xargs, giving access to the original exit value, that would solve the problem, but I am not aware of that.

Comment: Do you need the status code and the output in the same file? How do you know where the output of the next file begins?

Comment: The status code I just need to store in a variable (in the bash-script).

Comment: What does the file `F` look like? How do you handle arguments which have whitespace in them? Is it one argument per line, or..?

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what you want?

```
cat F | xargs bash -c 'java program "$@"; echo "Returned: $?"' - > Output
```

Or, as @rici correctly points out, avoid the [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html)

```
xargs bash -c 'java program "$@"; echo "Returned: $?"' - < F > Output
```

Alternatively something like (though I haven't thought through all the ramifications of doing this so there may be a reason this is a bad idea).

```
{ sed -e 's/^/java program /' F | bash -s; echo "Returned $?"; } > Output
```

This lets you store the return code in a variable the `xargs` versions do not (at least not outside the `xargs`-spawned shell.

```
sed -e 's/^/java program /' F | bash -s > Output; ret=$?
```

To use a `${program}` shell variable just expand it directly.

```
xargs bash -c 'java '"${program}"' "$@"; echo "Returned: $?"' - < F > Output

sed -e 's/^/java '"${program}"' /' F | bash -s > Output; ret=$?
```

Just beware of characters that are "magic" in the replacement of the `s///` command.

Comment: uuoc. `xargs ... < F > output`

Comment: @rici Copied from OP without thinking about it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it took me too long to figure out the details. In principle it works (thanks!), the two xargs-versions, but now I need to store the return-value in a variable, and instead of the hard-coded "program" I need ${program}; seems a bit subtle to me.

Comment: I am a bit worried by the sed-solution, and so I just save the returned value to a file. That solved the problem now!

Comment: @OliverKullmann I'm not sure that's meaningfully different but sure. I almost suggested that in the post but didn't figure it was worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the question is really not very clear, so I will make the assumptions here explicit:

1. The file `F` has one argument per line, with all whitespace other then newline characters being significant, and with no need to replace backslash escapes such as `\t`.
2. You only need to invoke the java program once, with all of the arguments.
3. You need the exit status to be preserved.

This can be done quite easily in `bash` by reading `F` into an array with `mapfile`:

```
# Invoked as: do_the_work program < F > output
do_the_work() {
  local -a args
  mapfile -t args
  java "$@" "${args[@]}"
}
```

The status return of that function is precisely the status return of the java executable, so you could capture it immediately after the call:

```
do_the_work my_program
rc=$?
```

For convenience, the function allows you to also specify arguments on the command line; it uses `"$@"` to pass all the command-line arguments before passing the arguments read from `stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel (and do not mind extra output on STDERR):

```
cat F | parallel -Xj1 --halt 1 java program > Output
echo $?
```